# SQL Query to LINQ for MVC with SUM and IS NOT NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

Can someone please help me convert this query to LINQ as I am new to using Linq which will then be used for google chart information.

```
Select Question.SubSectionName, SUM(Answers.RatingAnswer) AS Ratings 
FROM Question,Answers,Response,Section 
Where Answers.QuestionID = Question.QuestionID 
AND Answers.ResponseID = Response.ResponseID 
AND Question.SectionID=Section.SectionID 
AND Section.SectionID = 2 
AND Response.ResponseID = @0 
AND Question.SubSectionName IS NOT Null 
GROUP BY Question.SubSectionName;
```

What I've got so far :

```
var submitted = (from ans in db.Answers join ques in db.Questions on 

ans.QuestionID equals ques.QuestionID 
join resp in db.Responses on ans.ResponseID equals resp.ResponseID 
join sec in db.Sections on ques.SectionID equals sec.SectionID 
where sec.SectionID == 2 && resp.ResponseID == model.ResponseID 
&& ques.SubSectionName!= null
select ques.SubSectionName && ans.RatingAnswer)
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you try to do something?

Comment: can you please edit that to question, not put in comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on your comment this should output a grouping of sums of RatingAnswers:

```
var submitted =
    (from ans in db.Answers
        join ques in db.Questions on ans.QuestionId equals ques.QuestionId
        join resp in db.Responses on ans.ResponseId equals resp.ResponseId
        join sec in db.Sections on ques.SectionId equals sec.SectionId
        where sec.SectionId == 2 && resp.ResponseId == model.ResponseID && ques.SubSectionName != null
        select new { SubSectionName = ques.SubSectionName, RatingAnswer = ans.RatingAnswer })
    .GroupBy(a => a.SubSectionName)
    .Select(a => new { SectionName = a.Key, Sum = a.Sum(s => s.RatingAnswer) });
```

There may be a more efficient way of writing this.

I would also point out that to me the data structure seems flawed. That is, it seems either normalized incompletely or improperly. That's certainly for you to work out on your own.

Answer (score 2):

[Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com/) helps you to convert SQL to LINQ.

If you want to get better in LINQ, I recommend using [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/). However, LINQPad can't convert from SQL to LINQ but from LINQ to SQL.

Answer (score 1):

try this-

```
from q in Question
join a in Answers on q.QuestionID equals a.QuestionID
join r in Response on r.ResponseID equals a.ResponseID
join s in Section on s.SectionID equals q.SectionID
where s.SectionID= 2 and r.ResponseID= @0 and q.SubSectionName!=null
Group by q.SubSectionName
```